# Extracting value per year from a range

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like

```
ID    START        END             VALUE
1     2010-01-01   2013-12-31       RED
1     2015-01-01   2015-04-11       BLUE
2     2012-01-01   2013-06-05       YELLOW
2     2013-08-04   2013-12-31       RED
2     2017-01-01   2018-12-31       GREY
```

Desired output:

```
ID   YEAR     VALUE
1    2010      RED
1    2011      RED
1    2012      RED
1    2013      RED
1    2015      BLUE
2    2012      YELLOW
2    2013      RED
2    2017      GREY
2    2018      GREY
```

What i have tried:

```
select
     case 
     when (START > '2010-01-01' or END < '2010-12-31') = TRUE THEN '2010'
     when (START > '2011-01-01' or END < '2011-12-31') = TRUE THEN '2011'
     ...
```

But this doesnt get all values, for example the VALUE = RED for YEAR = 2011. Im getting VALUE = RED for YEAR = 2010, so just the dates when a year is represented in the start or end date.

Comment: OUTER JOIN a year help table/cte.

Comment: what is your dbms ?

Comment: Have you tried a stored procedure?

Comment: I have to do this "just" with sql.

Comment: What if there are two colors for a year? Show one row with both colors or two rows for that year?

Comment: And what DBMS are you using? What version? You may need a recursive query here.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i will take the last value from the year, this is not the problem. The problem is to get the data from years, that are "missing", like in my example above. With "normal" SQL, common table expression can be used.

Comment: Sorry, i thought sqlite3 is "normal". Need it for Django/Phyton.

Comment: Okay, I've corrected my answer to match the DBMS. I think that SQLite doesn't support standard date literals (e.g. `DATE '2020-09-17'`), but wants strings instead (e.g. `'2020-09-17'`).

Comment: Why is the expected result RED and not YELLOW for id=2 and year=2013

Comment: forpas because i have to get the latest value from the date. Thats not the problem. Thank you @ThorstenKettner, i dont know why u deleted your answer, but to break all in parts could work. Just need to check something.

Comment: My answer was wrong. I got confused with the date comparision. I've fixed this now and undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, START, END, VALUE, STRFTIME('%Y', START) + 0 Year
  FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, START, END, VALUE, Year + 1
  FROM cte  
  WHERE Year < STRFTIME('%Y', END) + 0
)  
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Year, 
       FIRST_VALUE(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Year ORDER BY END DESC) VALUE
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID, Year
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fuaqqrawq4DUN1sy17Bu83/2).

Comment: Correct. It should be added that recursive CTEs are available as of SQLite 3.8.3 and window functions as of SQLite 3.25.0. With the latter being five years old now, this should not be an issue, though :-)

Comment: @forpas thank you very much. I didnt know, that you can do a recursive cte. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE WHEN` only considers the first match. If the range is 2010-01-01 to 2013-12-31, then the first case matches and the row will be considered '2010' only with this approach. Moreover, you got the conditions wrong. A row is not in 2010 when start is after '2010-01-01' or end is before '2010-12-31', but when the start is less or equal '2010-12-31' and end is greater or equal '2010-01-01'.

select
case
when (START > '2010-01-01' or END < '2010-12-31') = TRUE THEN '2010'
when (START > '2011-01-01' or END < '2011-12-31') = TRUE THEN '2011'

If you want a very simple query that only works for a fixed set of years (e.g. years 2010 to 2020), you'd be looking for `UNION ALL`.

```
select id, 2010 as year, value from mytable where start <= '2010-12-31' and end >= '2010-01-01'
union all
select id, 2011 as year, value from mytable where start <= '2011-12-31' and end >= '2011-01-01'
union all
select id, 2012 as year, value from mytable where start <= '2012-12-31' and end >= '2012-01-01'
...
order by id, year;
```

This can give you multiple rows per ID and year. If you don't want this, then aggregate over this result.

If you want to allow for all years in the table, no matter which and you don't want to write a union all query starting with year 0, then you would need a recursive query instead.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE 
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE

set @MinDate = (select top 1 min([START]) from [dbo].[Table_1] )
set @MaxDate = (select top 1 max([END]) from [dbo].[Table_1]  )

SELECT [ID],year(tt.Date) as year , [VALUE] FROM [dbo].[Table_1] as t1
left outer join (SELECT  TOP  (DATEDIFF(YEAR , @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) Date = DATEADD(YEAR , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b) tt on tt.Date between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,  t1.[START]), 0) and  DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,  t1.[END]) +1, 0))
```

Comment: This code may (or may not) work in SQL Server, but it does not work in SQLite.

Comment: you can replace the code of generating date between tow date with this : WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (
  VALUES('2015-10-03')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
  FROM dates
  WHERE date < '2015-11-01'
)
SELECT date FROM dates;